# Open browser print window without using a package ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to print my whole page on react js without using a package. Is there any way to do this, i found [Window.print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) which does not seem to work.

Just want to open the browser print window. The shortcut for that is Ctrl+P on chrome so there could be a possibe way to press ctrl+p onClick of a button maybe.

```
<div>
<h1> Hello World </h1>
<button onClick = {DoPrint}></button>
</div>
```

Edit : Code to do this would be

Should work on all browsers except for  Firefox For Android

```
<button className="DoTest" onClick={window.print}></button>
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly "does not seem to work" about `window.print()`?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Could you elaborate how exactly `Window.print()` doesn't work for you, and attach the code to show how you used it?

Comment: Sorry i just migrated from js i did onClick= {window.print()} instead of just onClick= {window.print} my bad

Answer (score 1):

You could declare your page with an iframe:

```
<iframe id="idofyourpage" style="position: absolute; ..."></iframe>
```

And then print it with something like this:

```
var myPrint = document.getElementById("idofyourpage").contentWindow;
myPrint.focus();
myPrint.print();
```

Also remember that you might need to open the document and write some content to it depending of your functionality. However, I remember having used window.print() successfully, so you would also like to make sure you used it correctly, since it's an easier and cleaner way to get your page printed in a component.